# NHibernate HQL max and count values. How to access retrunded values from c#

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, hql

I am trying to get max amount and number of records in a single HQL(fluent nhibernate).
But after i get it how will I access it from C# code

Following is the thing I am trying to acheieve. 
Please note I have to use CreateQuery.

```
{

var MaxOffer = session.CreateQuery("select new map(  max(Amount) as Maxamount,count(*) as total) from Offer o").List() ;
object agg = MaxOffer[0];
Console.WriteLine(((object[])(agg))[0]);
Console.WriteLine(((object[])(agg))[1]);

}
```

Comment: yeah, I have not found an example that makes is clear how these "new map" methods can be used to populate these dto/model classes.